# restify + use() method - never call

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, restify

I try use "use()" method of Restify like that:

```
...
server = Restify.createServer(@options)
        server.use(Restify.queryParser())
        server.use(Restify.urlEncodedBodyParser())
        server.use(Restify.CORS())
        server.use( (req, res, next) ->
            console.log('TEST')
            next()
        )
server.listen() ... etc.
```

But "TEST" will never happen :(

@options is my local variable:

```
@options.name = 'test-server'
@options.version = '0.0.1'
@options.host ?= @options.host || '0.0.0.0'
@options.listenPort ?= @options.port || process.env.PORT  || 5000
@options.accept = [
     'text/html',
]

@formatter = new Formatter(@options)
@options.formatters = {
    # supported output
    'text/html': @formatter.html,
    # unsupported output
   '*/*': @formatter.error
}
```

Comment: @options <--- what is this??????

Comment: I add @options info...

Comment: thats not a valid format, do you know any javascript?

Comment: What is invalid? It's coffeescript...

Comment: you should tag the question with coffescript tag then

Comment: ok, I add this tag...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a solution... must be defined some routes like:

get(path, callback)
head(path, callback)
post(path, object, callback)
put(path, object, callback)
or
del(path, callback)

Comment: Please give some more details to help anyone who comes along after to understand the solution.